# which Wavelet is used for Jpeg2000 Image Compression?

Tags: image-processing, image-compression, jpeg2000, wavelet

which Wavelet is used for Jpeg2000 Image Compression ?

I was reading the Book on Wavelet Transform to find out how wavelet works for image compression but there are so many types of Wavelets mentioned in the book and i am confused which one is used for Jpeg2000 compression ?

These are the types i've found in the book.

Biorthogonal wavelet, Shannon or “Sinc” wavelets , Haar wavelets (the shortest), Coiflets wavelets.

P.S: I've no knowledge of image compression , just starting it with this project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article on JPEG 2000, two different varieties of Cohen-Daubechies-Feauveau wavelet are used: the CDF 5/3 wavelet for lossless compression, and a CDF 9/7 wavelet for lossy compression. (Both sorts are biorthogonal.) See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen-Daubechies-Feauveau_wavelet .

Answer (score 0):

[Gareth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599792/gareth-mccaughan)
is correct that
[CDF 9/7 wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Daubechies%E2%80%93Feauveau_wavelet)
are used for lossy compression, but **LGT** (*not CDF*) 5/3 wavelets are used for lossless compression. See
[this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000)
for more information on JPEG 2000 and
[this blog](https://tim.cogan.dev/lgt-wavelet/)
for more background on LGT 5/3 wavelets.